# Flutter. Can not run app only android device

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, debugging, sdk

Hi I have a problem since yesterday. Android Studio in Flutter project doesn't allow project to run on Android devices (physics and emulators). When I'm working on the kotlin project everything works fine.

Near Android devices I see the information: **Device not applicable for the "main.dart" configuration**
[image]

I already try:

- Clear `.idea` folder
- run `flutter config --android-sdk / PATH TO ANDROID SDK`
- Reinstall flutter and Dar plugins
- Reinstall Android SDK
- Change Android SDK
- I even reinstalled the whole Android Studio

**But still nothing. I can't run the project on Android devices (on iOS it work fine).**
I can run only if I Open Android module in Android Studio:
[image]
But it is so annoying constantly opening the project in Android module.

Does anyone have any idea what I have to do to run/debug project when I have open flutter project?

In this project I also have a problem with structure of project:

- Android Module -> **invalid item 'Flutter for Android' in the dependencies list**
- Library Dart Packages has broken classes paths:

[image]

[image]
But I don't know if it is related to my main problem.

[EDIT] Screenshot with expanded list of devices
[image]

Comment: You don't tell us about your main problem? What's the main problem? What are the errors thrown when running? please be precise.

Comment: My problem is that I can't run the flutter code on devices or emulators with Android system.

Comment: According to your image, you haven't selected any device. Is your device showing in the pop up list where it shows, No devices selected as given in the top image.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not see any android devices there to select. I only have possibility to open emulators. I add this screenshot to the main post, ad the bottom.

Comment: Can you choose the Pixel emulator or try connecting a physical device and then press the green run button which is beside the pixel 6 pro api 33 or press command + f10 button

Comment: The first image in which you show that it is written, not applicable for configuration main.dart is for android projects not for flutter projects. The green button is the one on which you hover and it says: `Run main.dart Cmd+F10`

Comment: The first image is not for Android project this is for Android devices. This error appears 2 days ago. Before I could run the project now after press green run I get: No Connected Devices Found

Comment: Did you see your physical device after connecting it in the list of devices.

Comment: no I do not see in the list of device to select. I only see on the list next to green 'run button' but as the emulator the device is disable and gray (the same view as 'emulator Pixel 6 Pro API 33')

Comment: No, the greyed out list is the list of devices for android project. You need to select the device from the flutter's device list which shows No device selected.

Comment: See: https://imgur.com/a/xUXAJlw

Comment: I know, but I have nothing there as I said. I can not choose any devices from this list because I do not see there any Android devices.

Comment: Can you run the same project from the cmd. Run `flutter run` from your android project.

Comment: No I can't. I get "No supported devices connected.". Because I did not choose any devices. And I can not select any devices because the do not show up in the selectable list.

Comment: Can you run adb devices after connecting your physical device to see if it shows in adb. Adb can be found in your androidsdkpath/SDK/platform_tools

Comment: Yes, I can see my physical device when connected to a laptop in the adb list. But still I can't run the flutter project on any android device.

Comment: Then I would recommend you to reinstall flutter sdk and open an issue in flutter repository